# Copy and paste data into Word. Interop.Word C #

Tags: c#, office-interop

```
public static void ImportInformationDoc()
{
    var app = new Word.Application();
    object template = @"C:\Post.dot";

    Object newTemplate = Type.Missing;
    Object documentType = Type.Missing;
    Object visible = Type.Missing; 

    Word._Document mail = app.Documents.Add(ref template, 
                                            ref newTemplate, 
                                            ref documentType, 
                                            visible);
    mail.SaveAs(@"C:\new.doc");

    mail.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

Hello! I can not figure out how. How to insert a new.doc again data from post.dot. Make it content on two pages the same.

For **example**, in post.dot:

On the first page: "Hello world".

In new.doc:

On the first page: "Hello world".

On the second page: "Hello world".